# VHDL execution order?

Tags: vhdl

In the following code, i have the line `row_count <= row_count + 1;`, and the next line I use `row_count` to access an array, `col_mask <= display(conv_integer(row_count));`. My expectation was that when the if block was triggered, `row_count` would be incremented and that new value would be used to access the array. However, when I run the code, the value retrieved from the array is 1 behind where I expect it, showing that the array is indexed with the current value of `row_count` before it is incremented.

My question is, why is that? I easily compensated for this by starting my counter at 1 instead of zero, but I'm very curious as to why it behaves this way.

```
            if col = "10000000" then
                -- Left rotate row
                row <= row(6 downto 0) & row(7);
                -- increment row count
                row_count <= row_count + 1;
                -- get column mask from current position in array
                col_mask <= display(conv_integer(row_count));
            end if;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

row_count is a signal (visible because of the "<=" assignement). signals are always updated at the end of the process. therefore, if you update a signal, the updated value is only available the next time the process is triggered (e.g. on next rising clock edge).

if you need to have immediate access to updated values, you can implement row_count as a variable. variables are updated immediately and assigned with ":=". however, note that variables are only visible within the process.

Comment: Rather than using a variable, it is better (especially when starting out with VHDL), to have a combinatorial `row_count_next` signal, which equals `row_count + 1;`. Variables tend to lead to a sequential coding mindset, which is something HDLs are not! Hiding combinatorial signals in variables just makes it harder to find timing errors later.

Comment: This question suggests the difference between the two operators <= and :=